# Gifted Chat append message from different class

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm still not sure how to get this to work.
I wanted to write a small chat app in expo.
Right now I'm using a Button that, when clicked, should append a message to a gifted chat.
I have two components that are not connected. One is called button.js and one chat.js.
They are both displayed in the App.js.
 I tried writing a helper function in chat.js

```
    updateChatView(){
        //Debug only
        // console.log("TEST");
        this.setState(previousState => ({
              messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, {
                _id: "MSG ID",
                text: "TEXT YOU WANT TO SHOW",
                createdAt: new Date(),
                user: {
                  _id: "USER_ID",
                  name: "USER NAME",
                  avatar:"USER AVATAR URL",
                },
              }),
            }));

      }
```

I can see the console output TEST, but the state can't be set, because it seems like the Component (chat.js) is not mounted. 
I use this code to call the function.

```
import ChatView from './chatView';
const cv = new ChatView();

//Render function
  <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Button" onPress={(e) => cv.updateChatView()} />
      </View>
```

I would think that the chat.js is mounted, as it's displayed?
I have no real idea where to start.
I tought about replacing state with redux, but I'm not sure if this would work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this one `messages: GiftedChat.append...` . And please show the code of this `GiftedChat`

Comment: This is from the react-native-gifted-chat framework: https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using redux instead of the state.
With GiftedChat.append you need to use the spread operator, but then it works.
One problem I still need to fix, is that the ID stays the same for every message.